# Setting the clock on a pro-lite LED sign from Linux

Tags: linux

I have these instructions for setting the clock of my pro-lite LED sign, but I can't get it to respond.  I send text to it like this

```
echo "<ID06><PC> Test message <E><EOT>" > /dev/prolite
```

Here are the instructions for setting the clock

```
5) SETTING INTERNAL TIME CLOCK
This is a special command to sync. or set the relative/real time clock of the display unit(s)
and it is the only GLOBAL command in this set of protocol. The format as shown below:

<TCCYYMMDDWhhmmssPH><E><EOT>


<, T, > ASCII "<", "T" & ">"
CC Century (19 = 19th century)
YY Year (00 - 99)
MM Month (01 - 12)
DD Day (01 - 31)
W Day of week (0 – Sunday; 6 - Saturday)
hh Hour (24 hour entry ONLY if displaying in 24 hour mode)
mm Minute (00 - 59)
ss Second (00 - 59)
P “0” = AM , “1” = PM (ignored in 24 hour mode)
H "0" =12 hr; "1" =24 hr display mode
```

Here is what I tried, I just used the letter T because I really have no idea what the ASCII means.  I'm pretty sure that's where I'm messing up.

```
echo "<T20120805003080010><E><EOT>" > /dev/prolite
```

This is to set the clock to 3:08PM, but the sign does not respond

```
 <E> signals end of text and <EOT> signals end of transmission.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or give me an example of how I would go about setting the clock?  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'sign doesn't respond'?

Comment: It doesn't accept the format, the time doesn't change on the sign

Comment: Have you tried `<T>20120805003080010<E><EOT>`?

Comment: Do you have a link to the full instructions?

Comment: [Link to communication protocol](http://www.pro-lite.com/PDF_folder/Protocols_TCXP_8.0.pdf)

Comment: @saluce When I tried that it set the century as '<2' and didn't change anything else.